# При вызове метода __getattr__, вызывается функция внутри нее

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Почему при вызове метода **getattr**, вызывается функция внутри нее

```
class Interception:
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        print("Trace: " + attrname)
        return lambda x: x

<input> obj = Interception()
<input> obj.start
<output> Trace: start
         <lambda function>
<input> obj.start(5)
<output> Trace: start
         5
```

Если просто вызвать метод, он отлавливает не существующий аргумент, но при вызове его как функции он передает аргументы

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, перевел

Comment: У вас в обоих случаях `__getattr__` нормально срабатывает, что конкретно вам не понятно?

Comment: Одно, как программа делегировала выполнение, в условии ссылка на функцию.  Кажется, что часть obj.start и (n), выполнились отдельно.

Comment: `Кажется, что часть obj.start и (n), выполнились отдельно.` - ну, можно и так сказать. В первом случае возвращается ссылка на функцию, во втором случае точно так же возвращается ссылка на функцию, и потом еще добавлением скобок эта функция запускается на выполнение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в IDLE если написать obj.start(  , и не выполнить, он так-же вернет сообщение.

Comment: Это скорее всего IDLE пытается получить информацию об этом атрибуте, при этом фактически срабатывает метод `__getattr__`, и выводится "Trace: ". Вот например в ptpython тоже интересный эффект при попытке ввести start после obj.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZsJn.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменим ваш код без анонимной функции для удобства:

```
class Interception:
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        print("Trace: " + attrname)
        def subfunc(c):
            print('called subfunc:',c)
            return 'from subfunc'
        return subfunc

a=Interception()
print(a.y)
print(a.z(999999999))
```

Который вернёт

```
Trace: y
<function Interception.__getattr__.<locals>.subfunc at 0x0000000001D06160>
Trace: z
called subfunc: 999999999
from subfunc
```

Как видно ваши ожидания с Z не совпали с действительностью. Тоесть **gettatr** так же возвращает функцию, и незамедлительно происходит её вызов.

```
print(a.тут_мы_получили_функцию('а здесь незамедлительно её вызываем'))
```